# Describing this solid in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, cylindrical-coordinates

Let $Q$ be the solid delimitated by the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$, by the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4x$ and by the plane $z = 0$. In cartesian coordinates, we can write: $$Q = \{ (x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ \vert \ x^2 + y^2 \leq 4x \text{ and } 0  \leq z \leq x^2 + y^2\}$$

I thought it was immediate that the solid in cylindrical coordinates could be written as:
$$Q=\{(r,\theta,z)\in\mathbb R^3:0\le\theta\le2\pi,0\le r\le4\cos\theta,0\le z\le r^2\}$$
But my text says this is wrong. Why? What would be the correct description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we rewrite the cylinder's equation as
$$(x-2)^2+y^2=4$$
we see that a ray in the $xy$-plane from the origin only hits the cylinder at $-\pi/2\le\theta\le\pi/2$. This is thus the correct bound on $\theta$.

Your bounds for $r$ and $z$ are correct.

Comment: Thanks. The bound $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ would be correct as well, right?

Comment: @MatheusAndrade no, since in that case half of the cylinder would not be covered. Please wait until it's two minutes after the hour to accept my answer.

Comment: Are you sure? If I plot a ray from the origin in the $xy$ plane with $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$, I can see that it hits every point on the circle $(x-2)^2 + y^2 = 4$, I checked this with geogebra as well.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade yes, you are wrong. When $\pi/2<\theta<\pi$ the ray hits the cylinder at _negative_ $r$-values, but we require $r\ge0$.

Comment: I see! Thanks for  the explanation.